# MYSQL: Using VARCHAR field as a POINT in geospatial query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, doctrine-orm

I've decided to detect distance between two points. One of the points is static -`35.735019 51.410041`, however, the other one is a point which is given by a database field.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
  r0_.restaurant_point AS restaurant_point_0,
  ST_Distance(GeomFromText('POINT(35.735019 51.410041)'), GeomFromText('POINT(r0_.restaurant_point)')) *
  100 AS sclr_1
FROM restaurants r0_
```

We stored `r0.restaurant_point` as a `VARCHAR`. Take the string below as an example: `35.73062161548168 51.410930156707764`

Although it would be worked if I change `r0.restaurant_point` with static value, it can't get measure with database field.

Is there anyway for binding this value or another way to resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To concatenate the value of the column `restaurant_point` in the string that represents the point, you can use [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

```
GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', t.restaurant_point, ')'))
```

In your case you are just trying to create a Point NOT from the coordinates in the column, BUT from the column name itself. you need to change your code as follows:

```
SELECT
r0_.restaurant_point AS restaurant_point_0,
ST_Distance(
  GeomFromText('POINT(35.735019 51.410041)'), 
  GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', r0_.restaurant_point, ')'))
) * 100 AS sclr_1
FROM restaurants r0_
```